# How to get A-B in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr1=array(23,43,54);
$arr2=array(34,23,3456,43,11,54);
```

I want to get elements of `$arr2` that's not in `$arr1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`array_diff()` is your man. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$new_arr = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
```

Hmmm, if that doesn't work, switch `$arr1` and `$arr2` around.

Manual -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php